# Symfony2/html2pdf bundle - CSS ignored in pdf file

Tags: html, css, symfony, html2pdf

I'm using `html2pdf` bundle to generate pdf File. I followed the documentation. The bundle works fine my pdf is generate. But the css is ignored. I've my css in an external file and bootstrap cdn. But there is not changes.

However I create a route to the view supposed to be converted in PDF, and the css works fine in the HTML view.

**My controller :**

```
public function invoicPdfAction($id){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager() ;
    $invoic = $em->getRepository('EcommerceBundle:Orders')->findOneBy(
        array(
            'user' => $this->getUser(),
            'validate' => 1,
            'id' => $id
        ));
    if(!$invoic){
        $this->addFlash('danger', 'La facture n\'existe pas ');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_invoic_user'));
    }

    $html = $this->renderView('UsersBundle:Public:User/invoicPDF.html.twig', array('invoic'=>$invoic));
    $html2pdf = $this->get('html2pdf_factory')->create();
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('real');
    $html2pdf->pdf->setSubject('Facture : My E-Commerce');
    $html2pdf->pdf->setTitle('Facture : n°'. $invoic->getReference());
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
    $html2pdf->Output('invoic.pdf') ;

    return new Response($html2pdf->Output('invoic.pdf'), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'));
}
```

**My view invoicPDF.html.twig**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Facture</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style_invoic.css') }}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahauwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body> 
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <h1> Facture de la commande  n° : {{ invoic.reference }} </h1>
     </div>

  ....
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**config.yml**

```
ensepar_html2pdf:
    orientation: P
    format: A4
    lang: fr
    unicode: true
    encoding: UTF-8
    margin: [10,15,10,15]
```

What I missed ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

html2pdf ignore the extern files
You must do write your css in your pdf thanks to : /* css */

Comment: So I have to copy/past bootstrap css in a style balise ?

Comment: This code is good for html2pdf : 

<style>
    .demipage{
        height: 48%;
    }
</style>


<img src=".{{ asset('img/logo.jpg') }}" width="200">

<h2>Billets - Musée du louvre</h2>

<div class="demipage">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>